# C++20 concepts support in CLang

Tags: c++, clang, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm trying to compile an example of some concept from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/regular) with Clang on Mac and it fails. How can I fix the issue and compile the example?

Code:

```cpp
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>
 
template<std::regular T>
struct Single {
    T value;
    friend bool operator==(const Single&, const Single&) = default;
};
 
int main()
{
    Single<int> myInt1{4};
    Single<int> myInt2;
    myInt2 = myInt1;
 
    if (myInt1 == myInt2)
        std::cout << "Equal\n";
 
    std::cout << myInt1.value << ' ' << myInt2.value << '\n';
}
```

Terminal output:

```sh
% g++ -std=c++20 -o a a.cpp
a.cpp:4:15: error: no type named 'regular' in namespace 'std'
template<std::regular T>
         ~~~~~^
a.cpp:6:5: error: unknown type name 'T'
    T value;
    ^
a.cpp:12:12: error: template argument for non-type template parameter must be an expression
    Single<int> myInt1{4};
           ^~~
a.cpp:4:23: note: template parameter is declared here
template<std::regular T>
                      ^
a.cpp:13:12: error: template argument for non-type template parameter must be an expression
    Single<int> myInt2;
           ^~~
a.cpp:4:23: note: template parameter is declared here
template<std::regular T>
                      ^
4 errors generated.
```

Compiler version:

```sh
% g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

What's interesting is that the example successfully compiles on [GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/KMY3nvc74) with lower CLang version (12.0.1)

Comment: clang on godbold uses libstdc++ by default, but on a mac it uses libc++. If you add `-stdlib=libc++` to godbolt, you will see exact same errors. So it's a library thing.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Yes, you are right. If I add the flag, compilation process fails on godbolt as well. But if I add `-stdlib=libstdc++` to `g++ -std=c++20 -o a a.cpp`, it fails with an absence of `<concepts>` library. Moreover, compiler warns that `libstdc++` is deprecated.

Comment: Your terminal output shows g++. Are you sure it's clang?

Comment: @einpoklum I think on a mac g++ is just an alias for clang++

Comment: @einpoklum Well it says so. Apple installs clang this way ever since they switched from gcc to clang by default.

Comment: libc++ and libstdc++ are not compatible and you cannot mix and match them in a single executable. Apple probably installs an outdated libstdc++ anyway. If you want to experiment, you may want to install the latest (real) gcc. Still not compatible with libc++-built code though.

Comment: Apple Clang doesn't support concepts at all I think and Clang itself doesn't include <concepts> header yet. Looking at how things are going, don't expect proper C++20 support on Mac for the next couple of years (Xcode versions). Maybe for Xcode 15.

Comment: @Zingam Well, actually, concepts as a part of the language do work on Apple Clang. They are usable and very convenient, however, they lack STL implementation.